Create a new Channel via Stream REST API
I'm attempting to create a new channel via the REST API. I know there are clients that make this simpler but I need to use the REST API for my set up. The documentation is here: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/rest/#product:chat-getorcreatedistinctchannel
For "members" it just defines "PaginationParams" which I'm not sure what that means? But in the other clients' versions of this call you simply submit an array of member ids. So I tried that and it didn't like the array. So I tried an object based approach and it didn't like that either. I can't find any better documentation so I'm just guessing.
Attempt #1
https://chat.stream-io-api.com/channels/messaging/query?api_key=mykeyhere
"{"members":["userid1","userid2"]}"
message: "GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "expected object for field "members" but got array""
StatusCode: 400
Attempt #2
https://chat.stream-io-api.com/channels/messaging/query?api_key=mykeyhere
"{"members":{"userid1":{"id":"userid1"},"userid2":{"id":"userid2"}}}"
message: "GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "When using member based IDs specify at least 2 members""
StatusCode: 400
Has anyone figured out the correct body for this call? My hope is to create a distinct channel for these two users. The users do exist already. And I've made other calls successfully so I know my authentication is set up right.
